# why calling an async function inside another function rise TypeError: next is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

i have 3 functions :

```
 const uploadImages = (req, res, next) => {

  UPLOAD_HELPERS.uploadMultipleImages(req, res, (err) => {
    ......................

    next();
  });
};
   
const resizeImages = async (req, res, next) => {
  
 ..............................

  next();
};

const getResult = async (req, res,next) => {
 .............................
  const newFile = new Files({
    owner : id,
    fileName: images,
  });
  await newFile.save()
 
};
```

i call them in routes a bellow :

```
router.post(
    "/upload",
    UPLOAD_IMAGES.uploadImages,
    UPLOAD_IMAGES.resizeImages,
    UPLOAD_IMAGES.getResult
  );
```

**at this level uploading images with this endpoint works**

The problem i want to reuse this code inside another function called createPosts() without re-writing all this

```
exports.createPosts = async (req, res) => {

  ..........................

  UPLOAD.uploadImages(req,res)
  .then(UPLOAD.resizeImages(req,res))
  .then(UPLOAD.getResult(req,res))
  .then((result => {

    console.log(result)

  }))
```

i got this error : TypeError: next is not a function

Comment: You're not passing a third parameter to `.uploadImages()`, so `next` is `undefined`.

Comment: adding next gave me this new error  ReferenceError: next is not defined

Comment: No, you can't just add the identifier `next`, it has to be an actual function that exists. Or else your other function has to check if it's defined before trying to call it.

Comment: so any sugguestion how to check if it's defined before trying to call it ? i did 
  `if(next){return next(); }`
 but this wont work too
`(node:8956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: next is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a third parameter to all functions in createPosts and herself.